# What is the correct preposition for "perfect fit"?

Tags: prepositions

I would like to polish my text and am not sure what would be the proper use of preposition in this phrase:

> *The idea of event loop is a perfect fit **to** the basic Arduino concept.*

or

> *The idea of event loop is a perfect fit **in** the basic Arduino concept.*

Context: there is a software solution that uses event loop as its main execution block and this fits perfectly (in/to) the concept of infinite loop used in every Arduino program (the infinite loop is an inseparable part of every program in Arduino framework).

Comment: I'd use ***for*** myself (or perhaps ***with***). But the choice has more to do with what's idiomatic than what's "syntactically correct".

Comment: Generally, I would say [something] is a perfect fit **for** [something else].  This is a fairly common expression.  I'm not going to say you should never use a different preposition, but expressions like this in English tend to be somewhat fixed. This isn't really a question of grammar, as such, rather it's about common usage.  The actual choice of preposition here is quite arbitrary to be honest. There is no rule that will tell you which to use in this particular context. You simply have to learn the expression, as it is commonly said.

Comment: @BillyKerr: On reflection, I think I might tend to use different prepositions in different contexts. *Smith is a perfect fit **for** the new position at work*, but perhaps *Because of the flexible working hours, this job is a perfect fit **with** my personal life*. Or perhaps not. Several prepositions are in a kind of "quantum superposition" here for me (so the mere act of trying to decide / observe which I *would* choose probably affects the outcome! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - yeah, I think it might work with "with" in some contexts.

Comment: *[his theory] is a [perfect fit **to** the data.*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=perfect+fit+*+the+data&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) There's no doubt ***to*** is the most common choice there, but I note the *second* most common is ***...of** the data*. Which sounds a little "off" to me, but I assume that's more of a "domain-specific" usage within statistical analysis, etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I think that's part of the problem here.  What sounds "off" to one English speaker, might not sound off to another.  There may be some regional variations at play here.

Comment: @BillyKerr: With something like this, I kinda doubt "regional variation" would be a big factor unless you assume that term includes differentiating, say, American English from Australian English. These kind of expressions are more likely to be encountered in written material, national radio / TV, or "international" cinema movies. Even possible variation between different social classes / professions is likely to be haphazard. It's not like many native speakers learn "their" dialectally-favoured local variant as children, which is what I normally understand by "dialectal variation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's compare examples culled from Google search:

- "perfect fit **for**": "the role", "your team", "your personality", "Brides & Grads", "Careers"
- "perfect fit **to**": ["baby ear soft infant headphone"](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B0C5XYTYRG), ["Buffet's 10xEBT Rule"](https://seekingalpha.com/article/4606431-enterprise-products-perfect-fit-to-buffetts-10xebt-rule), etc.  but the majority is "perfect fit to *verb*" such as "perfect fit to maximize", "perfect fit to replace", etc.
- "perfect fit **in**: "jeans", "swimwear", "[Men's Tailoring](https://www.kobo.com/us/en/ebook/the-perfect-fit-in-men-s-tailoring-1), but the majority is "perfect fit in *place* / *language*" such as ["perfect fit in real life"](https://www.boredpanda.com/aesthetic-perfect-fit-pics/), "perfect fit in English", "perfect fit in Los Angeles"
- "perfect fit **with**:" "brackets", "the flap", "Temp Staffing", "Jabra motion", "a variety of sizes", "Weight Watchers"

As you can see above,

- "for" is used when referring to *a purpose, people, or a social function*
- "to" is used when referring to a *concrete thing*
- "in" is used when referring to *something you wear, a location, or a language*
- "with" is used when referring to *something you use together*

Based on the analysis above, and knowing the programming technique you are talking about, I think the **best preposition would be "with"**, since you use the technique together with the concept of the Arduino hardware that is designed for real-time, event-driven controller projects.

But if you want to emphasize the *purpose* then you would use **for**, meaning a programming technique for the Arduino hardware.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the answers. This one appears to be the best! I could not recall other options than the two I asked about, so I learned something new again. I agree that "with" if the perfect fit for the situation :-D (sorry if "for" is not appropriate in this context, I tried to use it as I feel it).